# different corner radius value for each corner (CustomTKinter)

Tags: python, user-interface, customtkinter

How can I specified the value of one corner from the frame, I though I could use a tuple as a value of corner_radius but it returns an error.

this is the part of my code my code

```
        logoFrame = ctk.CTkFrame(master= self, width= 200, height= 100, corner_radius=(12,12,12,12))
        logoFrame.pack(pady = (24))
```

I was kinda hoping to make something like this
[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v7ZrB.png)

Answer (score -1):

Simple answer: It is not possible...

Long Answer: You can't. CustomTkinter does not work that way. The corner_radius is a natural number, not a vector. Setting the one value, governs all corners.

A workaround would be chaunging the bg colours..
You could use  _background_corner_colors which is a tuple and change 3 of the colours to match the background. Now it would  lokk like you having just one rounded corner...

But be aware that referencing leading underscore variables is a risk, and is considered bad practice. Variables are named as such, to indicate that they are for internal use only (in this case by CustomTkinter) . There is no guarantee that these won't change, disappear, or be subject to internal implementation changes in the future.

[Here is a Discussion about it](https://github.com/TomSchimansky/CustomTkinter/discussions/1914) ~ maybe it helps

*I hope I could help!*

Comment: you did help! thanks for the information